# How to convert a bytes to string in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to convert a bytes of length, say `n`, to a string in Solidity.

```
bytes memory ret = new bytes(3);
ret[0] = 0x41; // A
ret[1] = 0x42; // B
ret[2] = 0x43; // C
return string(ret); // results in ""
```

Doesn't work.

I get the empty string as result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this   ret[0]= byte(A); ret[1]= byte(B); ret[2]= byte(C);

Comment: Do you want to use `char` values for that? or can use just `A`, `B`, `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the go to code around here:

```
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 x) public returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    uint charCount = 0;
    for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
        if (char != 0) {
            bytesString[charCount] = char;
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
    for (j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
        bytesStringTrimmed[j] = bytesString[j];
    }
    return string(bytesStringTrimmed);
}
```

I'm sure you can change out those 32's to get the length needed.  But hope it helps!

Comment: What exactly does the function do?

Comment: So as far as I understand, the EVM doesn't store strings, it stores things as bytes.  So you can't store a string, you can just store bytes, which requires you to convert it if you want to do anything with it in Solidity.  You've probably seen a lot of other posts to change string to bytes and that's in order to store the string in a way that you can call this function to get it back to a string.

Comment: Can I run this in Python? I don't know how to convert this into Python. Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This function works correctly but will consume a lot of gas. You can use the fact that string and bytes are identical in terms of storage; it's only at the 'entry' and 'exit' points of the EVM that the values are treated differently.

You can use assembly to copy the data in 32 byte blocks like this:

```
function bytesToString(bytes memory byteCode) public pure returns(string memory stringData)
{
    uint256 blank = 0; //blank 32 byte value
    uint256 length = byteCode.length;

    uint cycles = byteCode.length / 0x20;
    uint requiredAlloc = length;

    if (length % 0x20 > 0) //optimise copying the final part of the bytes - to avoid looping with single byte writes
    {
        cycles++;
        requiredAlloc += 0x20; //expand memory to allow end blank, so we don't smack the next stack entry
    }

    stringData = new string(requiredAlloc);

    //copy data in 32 byte blocks
    assembly {
        let cycle := 0

        for
        {
            let mc := add(stringData, 0x20) //pointer into bytes we're writing to
            let cc := add(byteCode, 0x20)   //pointer to where we're reading from
        } lt(cycle, cycles) {
            mc := add(mc, 0x20)
            cc := add(cc, 0x20)
            cycle := add(cycle, 0x01)
        } {
            mstore(mc, mload(cc))
        }
    }

    //finally blank final bytes and shrink size (part of the optimisation to avoid looping adding blank bytes1)
    if (length % 0x20 > 0)
    {
        uint offsetStart = 0x20 + length;
        assembly
        {
            let mc := add(stringData, offsetStart)
            mstore(mc, mload(add(blank, 0x20)))
            //now shrink the memory back so the returned object is the correct size
            mstore(stringData, length)
        }
    }
}
```

If you specifically need bytes32ToString the code is even simpler; I can post it as a reply but it's probably not very useful. OP wanted bytes to string.