# How to implement function() tokenFallback and decode the parameter bytes _extraData

Tags: solidity, arrays, erc-223, erc-677

I want to use the ERC223 `approveAndCall()` || ERC677 `transferAndCall()` functionality in a contract.

I can take the *_extraData* string

```
x="0xe359292df082828f595466de72062f2a1182b077",["0x3d4c4ecB5CAe14f20b916C2936a9d9A16acF14c9","0xBe227eE70d1AD43C4d1C9e173eD0f96AFDdB8a34"],["10","11"]
```

And convert it into a `byte[]` using `y=byte(x)`

`0x307865333539323932646630383238323866353935343636646537323036326632613131383262303737`

but in the returning `tokenFallback()` function I can't work out how to convert this back into an address and two arrays of `address[]`, `uint[]`.

**Edit**:  Maybe I shouldn't be starting from a string.  Is there a way to stick addresses, ints, uints, byte32 etc. together into a byte format, and extract (assuming you know how they were put together).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a close look at that byte string and compare the values with the hex column in [this table](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/compilers/ASCIIChart.pdf), you will find your data simply being encoded to bytes. Assuming you would correctly [parse](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29295/how-to-convert-a-bytes-to-string-in-solidity?rq=1) this data and extract only the bytes of an address, I'm not sure if there is an implicit type conversion to `address`. But if it's just bytes you want, you basically just need to split the data string into parts.

Comment: I don't think the output is in Hex as there are no letters.

I really want to end up with an address and two arrays of address[], uint[], not a string.  The parse function looks useful in general though.  I'll bookmark that for later use.  Thanks